# Problem with Simplify, Sqrt, and Set: What's going on?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, assignment

I am having some trouble getting Mathematica to simplify an expression of the form `Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[1/x]`, where `x>0`. The problem is that x is assigned to some complicated form by the time Mathematica encounters it, and it fails to recognize that it will simplify. While debugging this problem, I wrote the following code that fails to simplify only when x gets sufficiently complicated. The cases involving `x0,x1,x2,x3` will all simplify, but the `x4` case will not. What's going on here?

```
x0 = a;
x1 = a + b;
x2 = a + b*c;
x3 = a + b*c*d;
x4 = a + b*c*d*e;
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a] Sqrt[1/a], x0 > 0]
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b] Sqrt[1/(a + b)], x1 > 0]
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b*c] Sqrt[1/(a + b*c)], x2 > 0]
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b*c*d] Sqrt[1/(a + b*c*d)], x3 > 0]
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b*c*d*e] Sqrt[1/(a + b*c*d*e)], x4 > 0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: This looks very strange. fyi, I found a [problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76082/adding-trace-produces-error-messages) tracing this when there are 4 symbols only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably some internal weirdness with the ComplexityFunction, but:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[1/(a + b c d e  )] Sqrt[a + b c d e ]==1] // PowerExpand

Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b*c*d*e] Sqrt[1/(a + b*c*d*e)], x4 > 0] // PowerExpand

(* 
   True
   True
*)
```

Comment: Yes, but `PowerExpand` yields `True` even without `Simplify`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: Of course it does. What would you expect it to do with the equality?

Comment: No offense meant.  I merely was observing that the use of `PowerExpand` does not explain why Simplify is not producing the expected result in this case.

Comment: @bbgodfrey:Oh, none taken! *Hypothesis non fingo* on *why* *MMA* is behaving that way, other than theory in my answer. Just offering a work-around...

Answer (score 4):

> *The cases involving `x0`, `x1`, `x2`, `x3` will all simplify, but the `x4` case will not.
>
>   What's going on here?*

```
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b*c*d*e] Sqrt[1/(a + b*c*d*e)], x4 > 0]
```

> Sqrt[1/(a + b c d e)] Sqrt[a + b c d e] == 1

With `x4` added, you have one too many variables for the assumptions to work. Maximum number of variables in non-linear expressions for the assumptions to be processed in `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` is `4` (the value of  `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` sub-option of the system option `"SimplificationOptions"`)

```
"SimplificationOptions" /. SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]
```

> "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4,
>    "AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 21, "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> True,
>    "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> True, "FiniteSumMaxTerms" -> 30,
>    "FunctionExpandMaxSteps" -> 15, "ListableFirst" -> True,
>    "RestartELProver" -> False, "SimplifyMaxExponents" -> 100,
>    "SimplifyToPiecewise" -> True}

You can reset this sub-option value to a large enough number

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 10}];
Simplify[1 == Sqrt[a + b*c*d*e] Sqrt[1/(a + b*c*d*e)], x4 > 0]
```

> True

Related Q/As:

- [Evaluating an Inequality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132476/125)
- [Simplifying expressions with head Max](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149952/125)
- [Using Inequality Assumptions)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153944/125)