# Evaluating an Inequality

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I am evaluating a parametric inequality conditional on some assumptions on the parameters. In the simplest form, here, I am assuming the numerator and the denominator are positive:

```
Simplify[(a/b) > 0 , a > 0 && b > 0]
```

This gives me "TRUE". But when I do the same for my big equations it doesn't give me "TRUE"; it just shows my equation is positive (i.e it just gives me (a/b)>0 as a result or (a/b)<0 if I write (a/b)<0 in above). Here is my code:

```
Simplify[(θ (-(-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) ρ - 
   (-1 +  p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β Subscript[g, B]))/
    ((1 - p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β + (-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) θ) >  0, 
  θ (-(-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) ρ - 
     (-1 + p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β Subscript[g, B]) > 0 && 
  ((1 - p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β + (-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) θ) > 0]
```

I am going to assume other conditions on the parameters instead of the positivity of numerator and the denominator. I have just started with these two conditions to make sure it works, but it can't evaluate my expression.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? Without conditions on the various parts of the expression, there is no way to tell whether it's greater or less than zero. Consider the simplest case: Simplify[a>0]. Is this true? False? With no conditions on a, there is no possible simplification.

Comment: I am adding conditions by assuming that both numerator and the denominator are positive. I expect to give me "TRUE" as an answer like the answer to the simplest form that I have mentioned. The simple form (a/b) works but it doesn't work for my inequality!

Comment: The expression I have posted is still in the format of Simplify[(a/b) > 0 , a > 0 && b > 0]. Aren't a>0 && b>0 conditions?

Comment: I have made the expression simpler. Now it is a ratio>0 followed by two conditions: numerator >0 && denominator>0. It still gives me the ratio>0 as a result not True. Even if I make one of the numerator or denominator negative, the result remains the same: a/b>0

Comment: Did you try `FullSimplify`? This now seems to simplify it somewhat. `Reduce` also gives a whole slew of conditions.

Comment: I tried now. None of them gives me what I want. FullSimplify just gives (numerator)(denominator)>0. I want to get an answer of TRUE or FALSE when I add some conditions on the parameters. With the current code it must give me TRUE but it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

As in these related Q/As ([Simplifying expressions with head Max](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149952/125) and [Using Inequality Assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153944/125)) the number of variables in your non-linear expression exceeds the limit set by the system sub-option `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` (which is `4`). Increasing this option value to `10` gives the expected result.

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->{"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 10}];

Simplify[(θ (-(-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) ρ - 
     (-1 + p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β Subscript[g, B]))/
     ((1 - p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β + (-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) θ) > 0, 
 θ (-(-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) ρ - 
     (-1 + p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β Subscript[g, B]) > 0 &&
 ((1 - p) (f p + (-1 + β)^2) β + (-1 + β) (1 + p - p α + (-1 + p) β) θ) > 0]
```

> True

To set the option back to its default value use

```
 SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4}];
```