# Using Inequality Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'm having getting Mathematica to use my inequality assumptions.  Here's a simple example:

```
$Assumptions = (v-w*x+y*z)>0
FullSimplify[Sign[(v-w*x+y*z)]]
```

Output: `Sign[v-wx+yz]`
(Meaning that the assumption had no effect)

However, if I put in the pieces separately, it gives me the expected results.

```
$Assumptions = (v-w*x)>0
FullSimplify[Sign[(v-w*x)]]
```

Output: `1`

```
$Assumptions = (y*z)>0
FullSimplify[Sign[(y*z)]]
```

Output: `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of variables in the nonlinear expression in your first example (`5`) exceeds the limit set by the system sub-option `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` (which is `4`).

```
SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]
```

> {"SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4, 
>      "AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 21, "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> True, 
>      "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> True, "FiniteSumMaxTerms" -> 30, 
>      "FunctionExpandMaxSteps" -> 15, "ListableFirst" -> True, 
>      "RestartELProver" -> False, "SimplifyMaxExponents" -> 100, 
>      "SimplifyToPiecewise" -> True}}

Set the value of  `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` to a larger number (say, 5) to make `FullSimplify` handle a larger number of nonlinear variables:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 5}];

$Assumptions = (v - w*x + y*z) > 0;
FullSimplify[Sign[(v - w*x + y*z)]]
```

> 1

Reset the value to its default using

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4}];
```

See also: [Simplifying expressions with head Max](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149952/125)

Comment: One last question: is there any documentation of what all of the SimplificationOptions mean?  I'm having a hard time finding anything.

Comment: @JeffAck, thank you for the accept. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any detailed information on `SystemOptions`  beyond what is available on the documentation pages [SystemOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SystemOptions.html) and [SetSystemOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetSystemOptions.html).